# How to write SQL query in following situation

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In a table , for example, have an ID start by 142963 , and there are 2000 record

```
So , the id are 142963....142963+2000
```

Then I would like to change the id to start from 740923

```
After that, the id are 740923.... 740923+2000
```

The field name is e.g. userid

How to update that? thanks

Comment: In SQL Server `UPDATE YourTable SET id = id  + 597960` (assuming not referenced as an FK anywhere). What RDBMS are you actually using? [In MySQL that might not work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11207946/73226)

Comment: I think you need to go for stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update forexample
    set userid = 597960 + userid
    where userid >= 142963 and userid <= 144963;
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something, it's just

```
UPDATE table_name SET userid = userid + 597960;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** table_name
**SET** userid= userid +(740923-142963) 
**WHERE** userid **BETWEEN** 142963 **AND** (142963+2000);

HERE I HAVE GIVEN YOUR VALUES BUT IT COULD BE USED FOR ANY NUMBER YOU WISH 
YOU CAN USE ARITHMETIC OPERATORS FOR GETTING ANY COMBINATION.