# Updating value, of a Column with PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with the following schema

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(7)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And here is the content in it.

```
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
|  1 | a     |
|  2 | b     |
+----+-------+
```

Question: I want to interchange the values in a single query so that the table now becomes

```
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
|  1 | b     |
|  2 | a     |
+----+-------+
```

I tried: `UPDATE myTable SET title = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN "b" WHEN 2 THEN "a" END;`

but it gives me an error `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'b' for key 'PRIMARY'`

What should I do?

A solution found here in one of the links seems the only way as of now but I am still looking for a better solution

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE prime SET title = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN "$b" WHEN 2 THEN "$a" END;
UPDATE prime SET title = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN SUBSTRING(title,2)  WHEN 2 THEN SUBSTRING(title,2) END;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: `id` should be primary key and `title` unique. You have it the other way around in your table definition.

Comment: The standard solution is to push 'b' to 'c', followed by 'a' to 'b', followed by 'c' to 'a'. Is that an option?

Comment: @Strawberry Not quite. I need to do this in a single query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to swap values of two rows in mysql without violating unique constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207574/how-to-swap-values-of-two-rows-in-mysql-without-violating-unique-constraint) (but it will be a bit more complicated to swap VARCHAR values than swapping INT values.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
START TRANSACTION ;
    UPDATE prime SET title = 'zzzzz$$$$$xxxxx!@#$%' WHERE id = 1 ;

    UPDATE prime SET title = 'a' WHERE id = 2 ;

    UPDATE prime SET title = 'b' WHERE id = 1 ;
COMMIT ;
```

---

Comment, not related to the unique issue:

Use `WHERE` in your update statements, unless you want to update all the rows of the table. Your statement:

```
UPDATE myTable SET title = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 'b' WHEN 2 THEN 'a' END;
```

(if it worked) it would also try to update all other rows (with `id >= 3`) with a `NULL` value because `CASE` has an implicit `ELSE NULL` part. Of course it would fail as the `title` is the primary key but in other cases, you would have undesirable effects.

Comment: Yes I agree with your comment. I could add `ELSE title` there.

Comment: That would work, too, yes. It would probably be less efficient though as it would check all other rows (that the new title is equal to the existing one.) It would also probably lock the whole table.

Comment: I don't think it would check for all other rows. `ELSE` here probably works like `default` of `switch`.

Comment: If you don't have a `WHERE` clause, then it means you want to update **all** rows of the table.

Answer (score 0):

with PIMARY key help to use ORDER BY `title`

```
UPDATE myTable SET title = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN "a" WHEN 2 THEN "b" ElSE title END WHERE id in (1,2) ORDER BY id DESC;
```

if not work change direction to ASC or ORDER BY title. And don't fogot ELSE. it doesn't work wiout it.

I use it with id, like that:

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `id` = CASE `id` WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 2 THEN 3 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE `id` END WHERE `id` IN ( 1, 2, 0 ) ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

all works fine,
but if update 0=>3,3=>2,2=>1 - 0 should update separatly.