# Update multiple rows with unique constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have two tables in my database, `foo` and `bar`. Multiple `foo`s have one `bar`, and contain a second column that controls the ordering of `foo`s with the same `bar`. The values used for ordering should be unique, so the table has a unique constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE bar (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  bar INT,
  `order` INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (bar) REFERENCES bar (id),
  UNIQUE KEY (bar, order)
);
```

What is the most efficient way to update the ordering of the `foo`s for one bar? For example, if I have this data:

```
id | bar | order
 1 |  1  |   1
 2 |  1  |   2
 3 |  1  |   3
 4 |  1  |   4
```

And want to reorder them (1, 2, 4, 3), I now have the following queries:

```
UPDATE foo SET `order` = NULL WHERE id IN (3, 4);
UPDATE foo SET `order` = 3 WHERE id = 4;
UPDATE foo SET `order` = 4 WHERE id = 3;
```

The first query is necessary to prevent an integrity error for the other updates. Can this be improved?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to organise the data inside a table, or assign new values in general

Comment: I don't care about the actual order in the table, I'm trying to reorder the results when retrieving them by `SELECT ... ORDER BY "order"`.

Comment: use `order by bar asc, order` and you will first order the data by bar, followed by order

Comment: The answer you are probably looking for is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207574/how-to-swap-values-of-two-rows-in-mysql-without-violating-unique-constraint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to swap values of two rows in MySQL without violating unique constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207574/how-to-swap-values-of-two-rows-in-mysql-without-violating-unique-constraint)

Answer (score 0):

The only I can think is you should have your update values in a separated table/query to make it more generic and can work with multiple ID

**newQuery**

```
 ID   newOrder
 3      4
 4      3
```

You update your `order` to null before update because the integrity restriction.

```
 UPDATE foo SET `order` = NULL WHERE id IN (SELECT ID FROM newQuery);
```

Then update with a `JOIN`

```
UPDATE foo AS f
INNER JOIN newQuery AS n ON f.id = n.id
SET f.order = n.newOrder
```