# Swap values of two rows in MySQL without violating unique constraint?

Tags: php, mysql, swap, unique-constraint

I tried this code

```
UPDATE testing_table t1
INNER JOIN testing_table t2 ON (t1.id, t2.id) IN ((1, 2),(2, 1))
SET t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
```

but seems to have this error

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '3' for key 'emp_id'

Let me know how to swap 2 column vales without violating unique constraints in mysql

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207574/how-to-swap-values-of-two-rows-in-mysql-without-violating-unique-constraint

Comment: yes. but the values are unknown. emp_id is unique and swap between 2 ids.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do this? primary key values are not supposed to change... If you need to swap, then swap all the other field values of these two records.

Comment: I need to swap the unique emp_id values where id in (1,2) not the primary key id itself

Comment: (1) Do you have a foreign key constraint on the column *emp_id*? (2) Is the column allowed to have `null` values?

Comment: yes there is  foreign key constraint on the column emp_id and null values are not allowed. @trincot

Comment: Is a solution acceptable where you have to allow nulls (temporarily)?

Comment: NO @trincot Its Mandatory

Comment: Is a solution acceptable which would temporarily insert a record in your referenced employee table, removing it once the swap is done?

Comment: Thanks for your response, if that's the case then what if the table already contains null? then entry of another 0 would give duplicate entry? In my case its already existing huge table and I wanna also swap email ids wherein email ids can be null.

Comment: Nulls are not considered duplicates, even if you have many of them. Does that mean you would allow nulls for *emp_id*, even if temporarily?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have removed. Assume emp_id and email are not foreign constraint and I also removed all null values from db. Please provide the code for this. But I tried to make the email and emp_id fields nulls where null already exists, then an error #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'email' is shown and same for emp_id

Comment: For the duplicate key error, please provide your code (`create table ...`, `insert ...`) that triggers the error, because you cannot get a duplicate entry just because you insert a `null`. It might be a message about another column.

Comment: 'CREATE TABLE `testing_table` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `emp_id` (`emp_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

Comment: This is the query

UPDATE `testing_table` SET `email` = '' WHERE `testing_table`.`id` =4


This is the error message - #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'

Comment: Note that `''` is the empty string, which is not the same as  `null` (without quotes). Alter your table to allow `null`, and then try to insert multiple `null` values. It will be allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySql this is not easy to do, as it checks the unique constraints for every individual record during the update, not at the end (only).

So in order to allow the values of a column to be swapped, you need to allow the column to get a temporary value that will not conflict with any constraint. So if you have a column that has a foreign key constraint, *and* does not allow `null` values either, it is going to be hard to find such a value in all possible cases.

For the following solution `null` values must be allowed. If they currently are not, then first issue this statement to allow `null` for the *emp_id* column:

```sql
alter table testing_table modify column emp_id int null;
```

Then:

```sql
start transaction;
    update testing_table
       set emp_id = null
    where  id = 1 and if(@emp1 := emp_id, 1, 1)
       or  id = 2 and if(@emp2 := emp_id, 1, 1);

    update testing_table
       set emp_id = if(id = 1, @emp2, @emp1)
    where  id in (1, 2);
commit;
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cdb0/1).

#### Explanation

This will first set the values to `null`, while storing their previous values in `@emp1` and `@emp2`, and updates the same records with the values as retained in these variables, but swapped.

The `if`s in the first `update` statement are just there to make sure the assignment returns a `true` expression and make the `where` condition succeed. Note also that short-circuit evaluation will make sure that those assignments only happen when the left side of the `and` operator evaluated to `true`.

Comment: How can I rollback if one of the update doesn't work?

Comment: If an exception is raised, you can detect and handle that via a handler and rollback. See this [question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905900/mysql-transaction-roll-back-on-any-exception) for how to do this. If there was no exception, there is nothing you can do. :-( What exactly do you mean with *"doesn't work"*?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this one. It should work for you :)

```
START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE testing_table 
    SET emp_id = 
      CASE
        WHEN emp_id = 1 THEN -2 
        WHEN emp_id = 2 THEN -1 
      END 
    WHERE emp_id IN (1,2);

    UPDATE testing_table 
    SET emp_id = - emp_id
    WHERE emp_id IN (-1,-2);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: thanks for your code, but i need to swap emp_id values where id in (1,2)

Comment: This code (as of now) assumes your emp_id column is not of type INT UNSIGNED, because unsigned columns do not accept negative values and will replace them with 0.

Comment: yes @Anton. Can you help me with the code so that unique emp_id are swapped between 2 rows based on primary key id?